# Pandas dataframe how to group by value, sort by descending value, then filter to quantile(0.1)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `(p4p5_merge`) that currently looks like this:

```
    SampleID      expr             Gene  Period                     tag  \
1    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996   
2    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996   
3    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996   
4    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996   
5    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749   
6    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749   
7    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749   
8    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749   
9    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749   
10   HSB195  0.214731  ENSG00000188157       4  HSB195|ENSG00000188157   
11   HSB195  0.214731  ENSG00000188157       4  HSB195|ENSG00000188157   
12   HSB195  0.214731  ENSG00000188157       4  HSB195|ENSG00000188157   
14   HSB152  5.062444  ENSG00000188157       4  HSB152|ENSG00000188157   
15   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
16   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
17   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
18   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
19   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
20   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
21   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
22   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   
23   HSB627  2.062444  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB627|ENSG00000174749   

              Consequence  
1   upstream_gene_variant  
2   upstream_gene_variant  
3   upstream_gene_variant  
4   upstream_gene_variant  
5   upstream_gene_variant  
6   upstream_gene_variant  
7   upstream_gene_variant  
8   upstream_gene_variant  
9   upstream_gene_variant  
10  upstream_gene_variant  
11  upstream_gene_variant  
12  upstream_gene_variant  
14  upstream_gene_variant  
15  upstream_gene_variant  
16  upstream_gene_variant  
17  upstream_gene_variant  
18  upstream_gene_variant  
19  upstream_gene_variant  
20  upstream_gene_variant  
21  upstream_gene_variant  
22  upstream_gene_variant  
23         intron_variant
```

I want to now group by `Gene`, sort by descending `expr`, and then filter the data frame down to rows that are in the  bottom 10% of `expr` values PER `Gene` group (the 10th percentile). So I perform the following:

**1) Sort by descending expr (SUCCEEDS)**

```
p4p5_sort= p4p5_merge.sort_values(['expr', 'Gene'],
           ascending=[False, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**2) Group by Gene and filter for bottom 10% of expression/gene (FAILS)**

```
p4p5_bottom10  = (p4p5_sort[p4p5_sort.groupby('Gene')['expr'].
                 apply(lambda x: x < x.quantile(0.1))])
```

Step 1 works how it's supposed to, but when I run Step 2, I just get this response:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (15,16,22,36,37,38,39) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [SampleID, expr, Gene, Period, tag, Consequence]
Index: []
```

If it helps, the R equivalent of what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
p4p5_bottom10 <- p4p5_merge %>% select(Gene, expr, SampleID, Period) %>%
    group_by(Gene) %>% 
    arrange(Gene, desc(expr)) %>%
    filter(expr < quantile(expr, 0.1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply your quantile directly to the grouby as follow : 
`p4p5_bottom10 = pd.DataFrame(p4p5_sort.groupby(['Gene'])['expr'].quantile(0.1))`

We have to apply pd.DataFrame() to convert into DF.

Comment: Thank you! When I run that, it works, but only retains the Gene and expr columns. Is there a way for me to retain all the other columns too? Or is there at least a way for me to turn `Gene` into a column in the result?

Comment: To extend columns you can add columns like this : `p4p5_bottom10 = pd.DataFrame(p4p5_sort.groupby(['Gene'])['expr','Consequence','tag','Period','SampleID'].quantile(0.1))` and to add **Gene** you have to convert it from **index** to a column with : `p4p5_bottom10['Gene']=p4p5_bottom10.index`